# How can I check if the Mac OS is in 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: perl, macros

I want to determine if the Mac OS in 32 bit or 64 bit.

Who can write down the Perl script for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the output of `uname -a` and see if it says `i386` or `x86_64` on the end:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
no warnings qw(uninitialized);

if (not -x "/usr/bin/uname") {
    say "Can't determine system bit mode: uname command not found";
}
else {
    chomp ( my $arch_type = qx(/usr/bin/uname -a) );
    if (not $arch_type) {
        say "Can't determine system bit mode";
    }
    elsif ($arch_type =~ /x86_64$/) {
        say "System is in 64 bit mode";
    }
    else {
        say "System is in 32 bit mode: $arch_type";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you want.

To find the instruction set used for `perl`, you can use the following:

```
$ perl -V:myarchname
myarchname='x86_64-linux';
```

(As opposed to `i686-linux`.)

To find the size of integers used by `perl`, you can use the following:

```
  $ perl -V:ivsize
  ivsize='4';
```

(As opposed to `8`.)

These values can be accessed from within Perl as follows:

```
use Config qw( %Config );
say $Config{myarchname};
say $Config{ivsize};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no perl programmer, but how about trying to add 1 to the maximum 32bit integer and cheching it against the overflown value? If it equals, you're on 32bit...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to call "`arch`".

A script I just quickly typed looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$arch=`arch`;
print $arch;
```

However, when I type in "`arch`" at my Terminal command line, I get an output of "`i386`". My Mac Pro tower is 64-bit capable (and some, if not all, apps run in 64-bit mode), so I'm not sure why I am not seeing "`x86_64`" output instead.